# Is it possible to access/edit kernel memory in C#?

Tags: c#, kernel, ram

I was wondering if it's possible to access the kernel's memory via C# and edit it.
If not, is it possible to access the whole RAM? Using ReadProcessMemory on the RAM without defining a specific process?

I am trying to search for a string in the kernel/RAM yet it has to select a specific process, and the process is cannot be opened by a Win32 application.

I've did some research and found ways about including ntdll.dll and use NtWriteVirtualMemory etc in C#, but is there any better way to do this (if it works)? Other than creating a driver...?

Thanks in advance for anyone willing to help.

Comment: The whole point of Kernel memory is that it is hard to get... You will probably need that driver.

Comment: Are you sure there is no way to handle this without using a driver? A driver requires me to go in test mode, which is what I am preventing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't access kernel memory from userspace (barring any vulnerability), regardless of the language. This would be a huge security issue otherwise.

You will have to create a proper driver, using the [Windows Driver Kit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg454513). Then you'll have complete access to the whole memory.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Let me rephrase that question a little. Is there a driver already running with Windows which would allow dynamic memory editing and such? And also, any reasons why including ntdll.dll would not work?

Comment: @John No, that would be a vulnerability if there was a driver giving arbitrary memory access to userland processes. And including ntdll.dll wouldn't suddenly make you run in kernel space. Every process runs at a given ring level, userland is ring 3. Drivers and the kernel run in lower rings. You can't access memory that belongs to rings 0, 1, 2 from ring 3, it's a CPU feature. So in short there's no way to do what you want to do without some sort of driver, by design.

Comment: Note that if you just want to read other process's memory, you can do that from userland. You just call `ReadProcessMemory`, and if you have enough privilege it'll succeed. But you can't just go and touch kernel memory from outside the kernel.